# Branch Integration failed: Team ID mismatch

Tags: ios, objective-c, branch.io

I am getting an error with Branch integration to my app. In my `AppDelegate`'s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, I check: `Branch.getInstance().validateSDKIntegration()`

And I'm getting this error:

> Team ID mismatch: 'xxxx'

So I go into `Branch+Validator.m` to check why I'm getting this error, and I find that while all the data fetched from the server is correct, I'm having this issue on this line:

`NSString *clientTeamId = [BNCSystemObserver getTeamIdentifier];`

More information:

```
+ (NSString *)getTeamIdentifier {
    NSString *teamWithDot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"AppIdentifierPrefix"];
    if (teamWithDot.length) {
        return [teamWithDot substringToIndex:([teamWithDot length] - 1)];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

And that's where I'm getting this error because teamWithDot is nil here.  And later:

```
if ([serverTeamId isEqualToString:clientTeamId]) {
    alertString = [alertString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@Team ID matches:\n\t'%@'\n",
        kPassMark,  serverTeamId];
} else {
    testsFailed = YES;
    alertString = [alertString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@Team ID mismatch:\n\t'%@'\n",
        kFailMark,  serverTeamId];
}
```

I have no idea why `clientTeamId` is being nil here and I never had this problem before.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Jackie from Branch here.

Could you please make sure your build's Team ID matches the value on your dashboard?
You can find it in the Dashboard under Settings > Link Settings, in the iOS section next to "Enable Universal Links." This should match your Team ID which can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action#accountSummary.

Note that if your Apple App Prefix is different from your Team ID, you should use your App Prefix. Your app prefix can be found from App IDs on Apple's Developer Portal.

If you continue to run into issues, please reach out to us directly at integrations@branch.io with your Branch app ID and any other details that may be relevant.